# Factory reset generic android device

Tags: factory-reset, recovery-mode, bootloader

I have a cheap generic Android tablet (a Groupon special) that won't boot. <s>My theory is that the storage is full because this happened to two different tablets after installing apps.</s> *update: I learned how to use adb to remove apps and this problem persists.*

It gets to a Android logo screen in the boot process and hangs there. The only hardware buttons available are the Power and Volume buttons. I have already tried holding down the Power + Vol Up + Vol Dn buttons, and that does not reset the device.

I tried `adb reboot recovery`, but that only reboots the device and then continues to hang at the same screen.

I tried `adb shell` `recovery --wipe_data`. This causes the screen to flicker a moment, and then I get a *Segmentation fault*.

I'm stuck. I'm not a big Android guy so all this is from searching online and I don't quite understand what all is happening. Any other tips are *GREATLY* appreciated!!

Comment: `adb shell` won't let you connect?

Comment: `adb shell` will let me connect, but if I call `recovery --wipe_data` I'm getting a seg fault.